# What is the equivalent, for an ArrayList, of LinkedList's "poll" method?

Tags: java

I want to call the equivalent of a LinkedList's `poll()` method, but on an ArrayList. How can I do that?

Comment: I guess it would be `arrayList.get(0); arrayList.remove(0);`

Comment: How about reading some documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinkedList.poll() - Retrieves and removes the head (first element) of this list`

To get this behavior with an `ArrayList`, you must get the first entry, then remove it.

e.g.

```
Object obj = arrayList.get(0); // retrieve the head
arrayList.remove(0); // remove the head
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method in Arraylist. if you want to retrieve and remove first element simply go for

```
ArrayList.get(0);    
ArrayList.remove(0);
```

for more info [see Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList don't has method equivalent to poll(), however we can write our own utility method to serve this purpose. Refer to example below. Here pollName() utility method takes first element from ArrayList and removes first element, which is in principal similar to poll() in LinkedList.

```
public class ListTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    listNames.add("XYZ");
    listNames.add("ABC");

    System.out.println(pollName(listNames));
    System.out.println(pollName(listNames));
}

private static String pollName(List<String> listNames ){
    if(listNames!=null){
        String strName=listNames.get(0);
        listNames.remove(0);
        return strName;
    }   

    return null;
}
```

}